# PDF Rendering Issues in Github

Tags: github, pdf-rendering

Example : https://github.com/kunal-kushwaha/DSA-Bootcamp-Java/blob/main/lectures/02-intro%20to%20programming/Intro_to_Programming_Notes.pdf

It says that : `unable to render code block`

[image]

PS : I have this issue for very long time and some people too , and got the solution , don't know why it is down voted , and there is not similar questions or answers related to this .

Comment: then how changing the dns resolves this issue ? thank you for the reply @KJ

Comment: hmm...thanks @KJ

Answer (score 0):

Fix -> Change the DNS to Google DNS in Network Settings

Google DNS -> `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`